# Canonical for overlapping [regex] questions

Tags: discussion, canonical, regex

<sub>(Sorry for the terrible pun.)</sub>

There are quite a few highly-upvoted questions on the topic of matching overlapping strings with [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex):

- [How can I match overlapping strings with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20833295):

  - Language: [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
  - Question score: 63.
  - Highest answer score: 34.
  - Accepted answer score: 23.
  - Creation date: 2013
- [Javascript Regex - Find all possible matches, even in already captured matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14863026)

  - Language: [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
  - Question score: 17.
  - Highest answer score (accepted): 25.
  - Creation date: 2013
- [Overlapping matches in Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/320448)

  - Language: [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
  - Question score: 49.
  - Highest answer score (accepted): 34.
  - Creation date: 2008
- [How to use regex to find all overlapping matches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5616822)

  - Language: [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
  - Question score: 146.
  - Highest answer score (accepted): 249.
  - Creation date: 2011

If I'm not terribly mistaken, [the reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075) mentions none of them. Which should be chosen and added to the reference as the canonical question?

Comment: So you want a overlapping question?

Comment: According to the answers to the linked questions, the "overlapping" match is **language-specific**: regex libraries in different programming languages provide their own way for perform such match. In such case, questions about different languages should definitely NOT refer to the same canonical. Moreover, I am not sure that it is a good way to discuss canonicals for different languages in the single meta post.

Comment: @Tsyvarev An honest question: Which answer(s) said that? I'm trying to find the best post on the topic to add to the regex reference, but I'm not sure which one is best and  need some help. All of them has at least one answer which recommends wrapping the original expression inside `(?=(` `))` or a variance thereof.

Comment: E.g. a "Pythonic" question has highly [upvoted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966891/3440745) about using third-party library. There are also answers about combining non-lookahead regex with iterations, and those iterations are written definitely different in the different languages. At least, the very example of using lookahead regex differs, as different languages has different ... "words" for express same things.

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833295) should be chosen as a canonical: its most upvoted answer explains both the lookahead and manual iteration approaches. Maybe additionally mention possibility of this functional being available in some libraries with link to answer to python question talking about regex module (and libraries in other languages that provide this if you know more).

Comment: @markalex: Imagine someone (e.g. me) asks about overlapping match in Python, and you point me (via "duplicate" mark) to the Javascript question. I open that question... and I **don't understand** every answer because their examples are written in the language I am not familiar with. I would think: what a useless link/site it is. Of course, you may *additionally* point me to the question about Python. I would found that Python question useful... and I would wonder: why that Javascript reference is ever needed in my case.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, finding overlapping matches is rather agnostic: you use `(?=(mypattern))`, or manually iterate through string and apply your pattern from every position. Do you really think this answer must be repeated for every language?

Comment: "Do you really think this answer must be repeated for every language?" - Yes, I really think that these answers (lookahead and iterate) should be repeated for every language **which support them**. E.g. in [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-specification) regex engine simply doesn't support lookahead. Should every reader of an answer check, whether suggested solution is supported for their programming language? Or should every answer be accompanied with the **exhaustive** list of all languages which support it?

Comment: "finding overlapping matches is rather agnostic" - There is nearly no such thing like "language-agnostic regular expressions": every programming language implements regex in its own way. The only well-known regex **standard** I am aware of is POSIX. And [they said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15377532/3440745) that lookahead is not part of that standard. I hardly can imagine a question about "language-agnostic regex" which could be useful as a duplicate target for questions in different languages.

Comment: Given that the reference question already makes provision for specific programming languages, IMO it would be appropriate to add **all** of these to that question under "Common Tasks".

Comment: "Sorry for the terrible pun" - why? They're traditional.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know about the tradition; I just don't think it was good :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up adding three posts to the reference:

- [*How can I match overlapping strings with regex?* § @AlanMoore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837608)
- [*How can I match overlapping strings with regex?* § @WiktorStribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903830)
- [*How to use regex to find all overlapping matches* § @DavidC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966891)

The first explains the `(?=(` `)` trick, the second shows a workaround by manually modifying the `.lastIndex` property ([javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)), the third makes use of a third-party library which supports overlapping matches natively ([python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)).

Thanks to @markalex and @Tsyvarev for their suggestions.